# product progression by production cicle

Tags: simulation, production-environment, anylogic

I'm trying to make a simple model where I can advance an agent that follows a specific production cycle.

[image: image of the model]

For example, referring to the image, the article A will be created and passes only through service 1 e 2 while article B goes only through service 1 e 3. they both conclude in sink, of course.

In the past I've used Plant simulation and with methods and tables I succeed but with AnyLogic I really had no idea how to do that.
I've tried with the enter and exit but with no luck.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You would use "SelectOutput" object for that. The condition to set would be based on your article type.

Assuming you have an agent type "Article" with a String parameter `p_ArticleType`, and your Source block creates "Article" agents, you can use the setup below:

[image]

(Note that in your case, the "Agent type" property should not show "Agent" but "Article"!

Obviously, you can then draw connector lines to the required service objects ;-)

btw: This is some very basic capability so I recommend you study more AnyLogic tutorials where this is covered as well.

Comment: I need to find a way for not using any type of connector lines between services in order to address the article in the right path that i have written in the production cycle; i have the above article A created by the source; at the end of the source block i need to read from a table/database (i suppose, that is the real question) that the next step is service1, so something like "read from the table/database service1 is the next step".take(agent) in an exit block. The problem is how to make the production flows between those services without having a real connection between them.

Answer (score 0):

Following your clarification, in that case, you *do* use "Enter" and "Exit" blocks. In the "Action" code section of an "Exit" block, you would write code to move your agent to the correct "Enter" block ahead of the next service block it needs. The code is `myEnterBlock.take(agent)`.

Please check the help and example models, there is a ton out there to do this ;-)

Comment: "myEnterBlock" should be read by a database imported from an excel file called e.g. "cycle". in the first row and first column of this table is written "service1" (string). how can i read the first cell of this table and use it in the code "myEnterBlock".take(agent)? i suppose something like cycle(1,1).take(agent). I was not able to find examples or models that could solve this problems.

Comment: check the tutorials on how to use the dbase. Sorry, but it is all there for you to learn (and worth doing, very powerful stuff)